# .htaccess условие редиректа

Tags: .htaccess

Как в .htaccess сделать условие редиректа ссылок вида:

```
http://site.ru/programs10/1-news.html
```

на

```
http://site.ru/news/1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^programs10/([0-9]+)\-news.html$ news/$1
```